# Can We change the colour of Checkbox in Material UI (React) table?

Tags: css, reactjs

[In the material UI table, I have used selection props for creating a checkbox in the material UI Table, in the header checkbox and body checkbox are there. The body checkbox color was changed by using selection props in the material table in that color was mentioned in options, But in the header, the checkbox color was not changed. I have tried inspecting code in the console in that I have changed the color in the browser and it worked but when I copied that CSS and pasted it into my project but it was not working......So guys provide me the solution for this problem. I need to remove that red color from my Header checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnmYS.png)

Comment: Please create sandbox with your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
 import CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CheckBoxOutlineBlank";

 export default function Checkboxes() {
   return (
  <div>
  <Checkbox
    icon={<CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon />}
    checkedIcon={<CheckBoxOutlineBlankIcon />}
  />
  </div>
  );
  }
```